# bullet physics moving dynamic rigid body accuracy in C++

Tags: c++, physics, bullet

I have m_dynamicsWorld with 1 static object and 1 dynamic.
I trying control dynamic rigid body in bullet physics.

I change position every frame while button pressed:

```
    btTransform t;
    t.setOrigin(btVector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));
    t.setRotation(btQuaternion(rot.x, rot.y, rot.z, rot.w));

    rb->setWorldTransform(t);
    rb->getMotionState()->setWorldTransform(t);

    for (int i = m_dynamicsWorld->getNumCollisionObjects() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        m_dynamicsWorld->getCollisionObjectArray()[i]->activate(true); // for all rb in m_dynamicsWorld
```

then simulate

```
m_dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(m_timeStep, 1 + 1, m_timeStep); // timeStep < maxSubSteps * fixedTimeStep
```

Dynamic object is moving but gravity does not apply for it and it does not collide with walls.
Seems like i control object, not bullet.
Then i increase fixedTimeStep and simulate:

```
m_dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(m_timeStep, 4 + 1, m_timeStep / 4); // timeStep < maxSubSteps * fixedTimeStep
```

With 2 or more (4 in example) fixedTimeSteps bullet apply gravity and collisions good. But simulation time is increased. On phone every millisecond is important.
I dont remove object from m_dynamicsWorld when transform, dont change collision flag to CF_KINEMATIC_OBJECT, dont set mass to 0 and then set back to positive.

1. Why bullet dont apply gravity and collisions well with 1 fixedTimeStep?
2. How is better move dynamic object without increase fixedTimeStep?

Please dont advice me use kinematic object, maybe i control car which should be affected by gravity and collisions with other dynamics objects.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: What game engine are you using for that matter?

Comment: Does bullet behave different in different engines and languages? I use C++ console application + SDL2 + assimp + bullet 3.17 build from source code with Cmake and models created in blender.

Comment: upvoting, although i have no answers; i always use variable timestep for desktop apps, and all seems to be super deterministic and accurate